# How do I extract data from TFS builds?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, tfs

My big project right now is demonstrating how to automatically build and deploy .NET projects with Visual Studio and TFS. Everything is going great except for one step. My boss wants these items recorded in a database for every build:

1. Deployer (person's username)
2. Environment (test, pilot, production)
3. Name of application
4. Build results
5. Unit test results
6. Deployment results
7. Build start time
8. Build end time
9. Unit test start time
10. Unit test completion time
11. Deployment start time
12. Deployment end time
13. Check in comments

I was able to find the name, build results and start time in the log file in the drop folder and write a PowerShell script to extract them and write them to a database. Any ideas where I can find the other ten items?

Answer (score 5):

You should check the TFS_Warehouse database; you can find the tables reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691.aspx)